# How to rotate a div Html layer?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a Div layer like this

```
...
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#newImg {
    position:absolute;
    left:180px;
    top:99px;
    width:704px;
    height:387px;
    z-index:1;
    background-image:url(../Pictures/repbg.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;

}

-->
</style></head>

<body>

<div id="newImg" name="newImg" ></div>
...
```

How to rotate it?

Comment: What are you trying to rotate? and in what way? Dynamically, statically, et cetera.

Comment: Rotate div layer 45 degrees after page laods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do it natively at this point is to use `-moz-transform`.

Details are here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-transform

This is *not* cross-browser compatible, though, so use at your own risk.

<s>Update: Apparently, there is also a jQuery plug-in that will do it for you:</s>

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Transform/

Probably a little more compatibility there.

Comment: That Transform plugin if for something completely different

Comment: I was going to make a comment about "fear of the obvious going unstated" and how this only works in Firefox, but then I opened the link and saw it in action using Chrome.  `-webkit-transform` apparently works, too.

Comment: @dur. Thanks I threw that second option up there without reading through the doc (as I was heading to a meeting).

Answer (score 7):

You can use [cssSandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/) to use the `transform` property which can be used to rotate elements in Gecko (Firefox), WebKit (Safari, Chrome), Opera and even Internet Explorer.

Comment: I voted for this one because it was here first, and because the sandpaper examples worked in the browsers I tested, IE7/8 and FF.

Im too lazy to check the jQuery example, though if it works, that would be my preference.

Answer (score 2):

This is a jQuery plugin that will rotate the image: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/

Answer (score 1):

```
//
// Rotate a <DIV> element
//
// - DIV position must be absolute or relative
// - Will use the center point of DIV as origin for tilt
//
// I think it will work on most browsers (including ie6, ie7 & ie8)
//
function divRotate( divObj, divTop, divLeft, divHeight, divWidth, newAngleDeg )
    {
    var radAngle = Math.PI * newAngleDeg / 180;
    var spinAngle = radAngle;

    if ( window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf ( 'MSIE ' ) <= 0 || typeof document.documentElement.style.opacity!='undefined' )
        radAngle = -radAngle;

    var sinAngle = parseFloat(parseFloat(Math.sin(radAngle)).toFixed(8));
    var cosAngle = parseFloat(parseFloat(Math.cos(radAngle)).toFixed(8));

    var m11 = cosAngle;
    var m12 = -sinAngle;
    var m21 = sinAngle;
    var m22 = cosAngle;

    if ( window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf ( 'MSIE ' ) <= 0 || typeof document.documentElement.style.opacity!='undefined' )
        {
        divObj.style.WebkitTransform = 'matrix('+ m11 +','+ m12 +','+ m21 +','+ m22 +',' + 0 + ',' + 0 + ')';
        divObj.style.MozTransform = 'matrix('+ m11 +','+ m12 +','+ m21 +','+ m22 +',' + 0 + 'px,' + 0 + 'px)';
        divObj.style.msTransform = 'matrix('+ m11 +','+ m12 +','+ m21 +','+ m22 +',' + 0 + ',' + 0 + ')';
        divObj.style.OTransform = 'matrix('+ m11 +','+ m12 +','+ m21 +','+ m22 +',' + 0 + ',' + 0 + ')';
        divObj.style.transform = 'matrix('+ m11 +','+ m12 +','+ m21 +','+ m22 +',' + 0 + ',' + 0 + ')';

        divObj.style.top = divTop + 'px';
        divObj.style.left = divLeft + 'px';

        return;
        }

    var sinSpinAngle = -parseFloat(parseFloat(Math.sin(-spinAngle)).toFixed(8));
    var cosSpinAngle = parseFloat(parseFloat(Math.cos(-spinAngle)).toFixed(8));
    var sinAnglePerp = parseFloat(parseFloat(Math.sin(radAngle-Math.PI)).toFixed(8));
    var cosAnglePerp = parseFloat(parseFloat(Math.cos(radAngle-Math.PI)).toFixed(8));
    var halfHeight = divHeight/2;
    var halfWidth = divWidth/2;
    var radius = Math.sqrt(halfHeight*halfHeight + halfWidth*halfWidth);

    var ulx = divLeft + halfWidth - radius*cosSpinAngle + sinAnglePerp*halfHeight;
    var uly = divTop + halfHeight - radius*sinSpinAngle + cosAnglePerp*halfHeight;

    var urx = radius*cosSpinAngle + divLeft + halfWidth + sinAnglePerp*halfHeight;
    var ury = radius*sinSpinAngle + divTop + halfHeight + cosAnglePerp*halfHeight;

    var lrx = radius*cosSpinAngle + divLeft + halfWidth - sinAnglePerp*halfHeight;
    var lry = radius*sinSpinAngle + divTop + halfHeight - cosAnglePerp*halfHeight;

    var llx = divLeft + halfWidth - radius*cosSpinAngle - sinAnglePerp*halfHeight;
    var lly = divTop + halfHeight - radius*sinSpinAngle - cosAnglePerp*halfHeight;

    divObj.style.filter = "filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix( M11="+m11+", M12="+m12+", M21="+m21+", M22="+m22+", sizingMethod='auto expand' );";

    var spinTop = Math.min( uly, ury, lry, lly );
    var spinRight = Math.max( ulx, urx, lrx, llx );
    var spinBottom = Math.max( uly, ury, lry, lly );
    var spinLeft = Math.min( ulx, urx, lrx, llx );

    divObj.style.top = spinTop + 'px';
    divObj.style.right = spinRight + 'px';
    divObj.style.bottom = spinBottom + 'px';
    divObj.style.left = spinLeft + 'px';
    }
```